# Why can I write to `/users` with these Firebase Database rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have read the Google Firebase Database Security Rules documentation and I implemented this following rule in my rules file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that testing it in the simulator I saw that I can read and write everything in *users*, like there is no rule.
Is that a Firebase Database problem? How can I solve it?

Here is my test:
[image: Firebase database test]

Here is the link of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables

Comment: What kind of authentication did you use in the simulator? And are these all your security rules?

Comment: With these rules, you should not be able to write to `/users`. Can you share more information (as Andre requested) and a screenshot of the simulator showing the succeeding (simulated) write?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a screen of my test @AndréKool

Comment: Your screenshot does not match the rules you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules in your screenshot are different from the ones you posted before.

In Firebase Database security model, permissions cascades down: once you give a user read or write permission on a node, you cannot take that permission away on a lower level. See the [documentation on security rules for more information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade).

If you remove the top-level `".write": "auth !== null"`, you will find that you can no longer write to `/users` and can only write to `/users/uid123` if you're user `uid123`.